# some css of same file getting processed some not

Tags: 7, theming

In my custom theme I have two stylesheets; style.css and nice-menu-custom.css.

If I would change some silly old css for testing - like `body{color:lime;}` it would affect the site as normal. However, some other css changes to the same file that get uploaded just simply don't affect the site. None of the width or float properties are working I have the impression.

You would think I'm just not writing proper css, but the thing is if I make the same changes in firebug, it works fine. for instance `body{width:50%;}` does it's job when using firebug, not when uploading that same code from my stylesheet (i.e. the same stylesheet as from which I upload the changes that DO work) on the server.

I verified if the new changes actually uploaded by trying to upload the changes, shutting down the FTP program and then starting a different ftp program to see if these changes would be stored on the server. And they were.

**Made sure:**
Caches were cleared often
CSS Compression turned off

**So in short:** if I go and see in chrome developer tools, to read my stylesheet from the server, under the 'resources' tab -second from left, I can see the changes to my stylesheet that I uploaded and should work. Yet when you look at the site the changes aren't made. Plus if I made the same changes using the developer tools themselves, under the first tab 'elements', the changes would actually take effect. I just don't understand.

Comment: Do you have CSS aggregation turned on? Either turn it off if you're developing or clear Drupal's caches for the CSS changes to be picked up

Comment: yes css compression turned off. Caches were cleared extensively as well. Like I said, color properties uploaded actually work on same file, width and float properties don't.

Comment: Can you share a link to the site with the problem? What you're describing is illogical as far as I can tell; if the browser is loading some styles the only way it could ignore others is if there are further rules overriding them

Comment: sure: www.breinwijzer.be/festidev12345

Comment: Cool, can you point me to a rule in one of the CSS files that should be working but isn't?

Comment: well the problem is the actual code that doens't work is because doesn't 'reach' the output so can't be seen on firebug even. I've set `body{width:50%;}` (line number 221) for now just to make sure. Keep in mind that I made sure that I uploaded this rule to the server and it's actually stored on the server as such.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6074/discussion-between-ghd64-and-clive)

Comment: I accidentally clicked the 'move to chat' link. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a syntax error after all...forget one curly bracket somewhere in my stylesheet.
I never expected a syntax error in css to cause this kind of difficulties. I.o.w. I unconsciously assumed it couldn't be syntax and therefore it never crossed my mind. Lesson learned: never assume even when you don't realise you're assuming!